# The {columns} tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

I suggested a new [multiple-columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-columns) tag in [3 column layout in LaTeX (1st only graphics, 2nd and 3rd text)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111265/5764) [It was subsequently removed/replaced](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/111265/revisions) with [columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns). However, in my opinion, there's some confusion as to the use of this tag.

The tag excerpt for [columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns) relate specifically to that of [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables):

> [columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns) is specifically about columns in [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) (though often the latter tag will suffice). If your question is about [two-column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-column) documents or the [multicol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multicol) package, use the respective tag instead.

However, what about a three-column (or more) layout that doesn't use [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) like in the above question? What about the `columns` and `column` environment of a `frame` in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)?

Bottom line: We need to work on the [columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns) tag. I'm soliciting some feedback on a shake-up of this columnar conundrum.

Comment: Yeah! And sorry for being *that* guy again, but both of those tags (`multicol` and `two-column`) are LaTeX-centric, like many others, without there being a catch-all tag for the general case covering all formats.

Answer (score 7):

I was the one who removed the new [multiple-columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-columns) tag. Thanks to Werner for raising the issue here at Meta.

1. As Werner correctly observes, there's no proper tag for a *three-column (or more) layout that doesn't use `multicol`"*. Sometimes the [two-column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-column) tag is used for such questions (e.g., in [Is a three-column footnote layout possible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69458/is-a-three-column-footnote-layout-possible)), sometimes the [columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns) tag.
2. The tag wiki excerpt for the [columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns) tag correctly describes its predominant use; this does not mean, however, that the creation of this tag was a sound idea. (Most, if not all [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) problems are about "columns" in a way.) Note that there is a specific, though seldom-used [multicolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multicolumn) tag *"for questions concerning the formatting of table cells that span several columns"*.

My bottom line is that *if* a general tag is needed for case 1, I'd rather not create a new tag, but redefine the existing [columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns) tag. In any case, this tag should be removed from questions also tagged with [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables), and the [multicolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multicolumn) tag added instead to those [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) questions where it is missing.

Comment: I find @tohecz's suggestion to add the least amount of labour to housekeeping *and* it makes sense (the creation of a tag synonym [tag:column-typesetting]. What's your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the tag [two-column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-column) serves the purpose of [three-column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-column) just right. The only problem is the name. Hence I suggest adding [column-typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/column-typesetting) as its synonym. This would not create a new tag (which seems to be too much, because then [two-column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-column) would be a subset of this tag), yet it would make clear what the situation is. The tag wiki would get changed, too.

As for [columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/columns), breifly looking through its list of questions, it seems to serve a purpose as it is, despite being a subset of [tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tables) by nature. I would not change it, I would only add a notice to its tag wiki about [column-typesetting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/column-typesetting).

Answer (score 2):

I'll join @morsburg in being "that guy". I posted a question having to do with two-column (non-table) layout in ConTeXt. I couldn't find a tag that applied. The two- or multi-column tags I found were all specific either to tables ({multicolumn}) or to a particular LaTeX package ({multicol}, {two-column}).

The {two-column} tag would seem to fit best, except for the fact that its description links it to the `twocolumn` package. However it seems to me that the description could be changed; a tag specific to the `twocolumn` package should probably be called {twocolumn} anyway (no hyphen). IMO.

On the other hand, I'm not sure how much value there is in having separate tags for questions about dual-column issues vs. triple-or-more. From my point of view it would be ideal to have a generic tag for multicolumn (non-table) layout, regardless of the macro package used (LaTeX or otherwise). But that collides with the existing tags {multicol} and {multi-column}, so something would have to give. Maybe use {multi-column-page} to refer to this, as opposed to tables?